# The same node.js backend service, behaves different for the same request from different clients

Tags: node.js, cors, azure-web-app-service, fetch-api

There is a backend service which is resides on azure portal and developed with node.js by using Express.js

Requests are sending from an azure devops extension.

Most of the user's requests are successful but just a few users stuck on cors errors.

The cors error is

> Access to fetch at ..... from origin .... has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> request resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
> request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource wiht CORS disabled.

A part of node.js server code (probably there are unnecessary parts in it)

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.use(function (req, res, next) { 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    next();
});
```

Successful request headers

[image]

Failed request headers

[image]

A get method example from client code

```
export function getTheValue() {
    return fetch('https://....../.....')
        .then(response => {
            return response.text();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return reject(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: You should allow cros in ‘https://....../.....’ server side.

Comment: I tried it before actually